# Why does my swap partition not appear in GParted (runnning Linux Mint in VMWare)?

Tags: linux, partitioning, vmware, gparted, swap

I'm running Linux Mint 17 in VMWare. htop reports that I have a swap of size 8187MB:

http://postimg.org/image/a54es37wd/

I'd like to increase this but GParted doesn't show any swap partition:

http://postimg.org/image/94hl5vp8l/

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your system is set up you might have a swap file rather than a swap partition. Linux can use swap files the same way as Windows does. In this case you will obviously not see your swap in Gparted as it will be just a file within the file system of one of your partitions

To check it, take a look at your `/etc/fstab` and look for swap entry

Oh, and also, I would not recommend you to increase the size of swap unless you have a very good reason for it. Your 8187MB is massive, maybe even more than you need. You might consider decreasing it (but this is just my opinion)

Comment: I am not sure 8GB is so very large: it depends how many programs you are running simultaneously and how much memory each uses. I would never discourage a swap file which is bigger than necessary, because Linux grinds to a halt when it runs out of swap space, since you cannot get programs into memory to terminate them.

Comment: For anyone coming across this post and wondering about the right swap size: here's the recommendation in the Ubuntu docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq It heavily depends on the question if you use hibernation (suspend to disk) or not...

Comment: The answer dates back to 2014... With modern PCs having more RAM swap of 8GB no longer seems excessive